# Firefox Add-On SDK - Script don't run

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, browser-addons

So first I did a

```
jpm init
```

in a folder dedicated to it.

Then I would like to do basic DOM manipulation with certain page.

That's what I've done :

ff-main.js:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: /\/*.facebook\.*/,
    contentScriptFile: [
        data.url("jquery-2.2.1.min.js"),
        data.url("script.js")
    ]
});
```

script.js

```
window.alert('Hey!');
```

At the moment it is not real DOM manipulation, but it still does not work. It uses RegEx expressions to load only on facebook, with all http/https/www/m + .com .co.uk .nz .fr .de .it .ru (lol).

Then I did basic

```
jpm xpi
jpm sign ...
```

When I load page after reboot of Firefox, it does not do anything.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) in the [`include`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod(options)) property of the [options object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod(options)) for [`PageMod`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod). When doing so, your RegExp:

> must match **the entire URL, not just a subset**, and has global, ignoreCase, and multiline disabled.

For more detail, you can see the [discussion on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/util_match-pattern#Regular_Expressions). If you have already visited this page, you may need to hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>, as I just updated some of the RegExp examples.

Your RegExp is `/\/*.facebook\.*/`.  There is no possibility that this will match the entirety of **any** valid URL. It currently would match things like:

```
.facebook
Afacebook
//////////////Bfacebook................
```

But, would *not* match:

```
http://www.facebook.com/
```

Thus, your `PageMod` will never be applied.

You want something like:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: /[^:/]+:\/\/[^/]*\.facebook\.([^/.]*|co\.uk)\/.*/, 
    contentScriptFile: [
        data.url("jquery-2.2.1.min.js"),
        data.url("script.js")
    ]
});
```

However, it would be more secure to list the [top level domains (TLDs)](http://top%20level%20domain%20definition) which you want to match. You have to choose if you want to match too many domains (all TLDs, or all domains containing `facebook`), or only match those which you have verified belong to Facebook. Which you choose will depend on what your add-on does, and how you want to balance ease of use for your users vs. security of not running on domains which are close to `facebook`. Ideally, you would determine all domains which are owned by facebook which show the content you desire and include those.

An example of an `include` which encompasses the domains you have listed in the question:

```
    include: /[^:/]+:\/\/[^/]*\.facebook\.(com|co\.uk|nz|fr|de|it|ru)\/.*/,
```

### Complete SDK add-on:

Here is the complete Firefox Add-on SDK extension which I used for testing:

*package.json*:

```json
{
    "title": "Test PageMod RegExp",
    "name": "pagemodregexp1",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Test using a RegExp with PageMod",
    "main": "index.js",
    "author": "Makyen",
    "engines": {
        "firefox": ">=38.0a1",
        "fennec": ">=38.0a1"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "keywords": [
        "jetpack"
    ]
}
```

*index.js*:

```js
var self = require("sdk/self");
var data = self.data;

var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
    //Works (but matches probably bad domain facebook.co.uk):
    //include: /[^:/]+:\/\/[^/]*\.facebook\.([^/.]*|co\.uk)\/.*/,
    //Works (but matches probably bad domain facebook.co.uk):
    //include: /[^:/]+:\/\/[^/]*\.facebook\.(com|co\.uk|nz|fr|de|it|ru)\/.*/,
    //Works:
    include: /[^:/]+:\/\/[^/]*\.facebook\.com\/.*/,


    contentScriptFile: [
//        data.url('jquery-2.2.1.min.js'),
        data.url('contentScript.js')
    ]
});
```

*data/contentScript.js*:

```js
window.alert('contentScript.js loaded. URL=' + document.URL);
console.log('contentScript.js loaded. URL=' + document.URL);
```

Console output when navigating to `facebook.com` (along with alerts for each `console.log()`):

```
console.log: pagemodregexp1: contentScript.js loaded. URL=https://staticxx.facebook.com/common/referer_frame.php
console.log: pagemodregexp1: contentScript.js loaded. URL=https://staticxx.facebook.com/common/referer_frame.php
console.log: pagemodregexp1: contentScript.js loaded. URL=https://www.facebook.com/
```

A note on the domains you listed:

```
facebook.com:   valid
facebook.co.uk: broken good chance it is not be owned by Facebook
                Whois shows registered to: Technomicom Inc.
                NOT registered to Facebook UK LTD (& uses a different physical address)
facebook.nz:    invalid: Server not found
facebook.fr:    valid: redirects to fr-fr.facebook.com
facebook.de:    valid: redirects to de-de.facebook.com
facebook.it:    valid: redirects to facebook.com
facebook.ru:    invalid: Server not found
```

Given that it appears Facebook redirects all alternate domains to `facebook.com`, I would suggest not including any other domain in your match other than `facebook.com`:

```
include: /[^:/]+:\/\/[^/]*\.facebook\.com\/.*/,
```

Comment: I can't get it working with what you propose too.
I finally tried `/.*facebook.*/` and it doesn't work either way.
Can you try on your machine to see if it's a problem tied to another stuff?

Comment: TLDs are not a problem of security in the type of app I want to make.
It would only mess their phishing code lol

Comment: It must be able then to perform commands as such : `$('div[role="article"]').css('backgroundColor', 'blue');`

Comment: @MiguelMoncada,  Sorry, the final example I showed had two extra `.` characters. I had tested with the one in the `pageMod.PageMod(` code, and then wrote the last one without testing (I should have tested it). I have added a complete, tested add-on with 3 different, tested, RegExp match patterns. I also added a comment about the various domains you are trying to match. Based on Facebook redirecting all valid domains to subdomains of `facebook.com` & that there is a probably bad domain in your list, `facebook.co.uk`, I would suggest having only the domain `facebook.com` in your match pattern.

Comment: @MiguelMoncada, as to the site: `regexr.com`: I'm not sure if I've ever used it. I may have. I have only very rarely used sites to test regular expressions. However, some are quite good.

Comment: @MiguelMoncada, It sounds like you may be having problems in other areas than just your match pattern. Any other problems are not seen in the limited code included in the question.  I would suggest copying the entire directory you are using for developing your add-on. Then, in that directory, simplifying what you are doing down to the very basics. This will allow you to determine where the problem, or problems, are.

Comment: @MiguelMoncada, My issue with `regexr.com` is they don't explicitly state which regular expression syntax they are using. There are [many different implementations of regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tools.html). While the concepts are similar across them, actual syntax details vary (to some degree). Certainly, the features available in each implementation vary. I have used http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for information on different implementations. I don't think they have a tester. When using one, be sure they explicitly say they are using JavaScript RegExp.